# No menu in some applications

Tags: unity, menu-bar

Suddenly in some application Ubuntu stopped showing the menu bar (having buttons for maximize, minimize, close) and also it only starts them on the top left corner, and without the menu bar moving them is not easy.

However, this is specific to some applications. For example, Firefox and Netbeans have the menu bar but Nautilus and Terminal do not have it.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I just updated it. Maybe the problem is relevant to the update.

A sample snapshot of Terminal:
[image: A sample snapshot of Terminal]

Comment: Try resetting window decorator: `gtk-window-decorator --replace`

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. For some reason that I don't know, the programs appear at some place where their menu bar appear under the bar at the top of the screen. Using Ctrl+Drag made the menu bar visible.